# N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository Phusion Passenger

Tags: passenger

please help me, i don't know how to solve this message :

```
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger jammy InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

I am installing Phusion Passenger standalone not combine with Nginx, i read the doc in [Phusion](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/docs/advanced_guides/install_and_upgrade/standalone/install/oss/jammy.html)

I am using OS
Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy LTS
Nginx

i need help how to make my Phusion Passenger is not show error skipping like that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i was forgot to change the list in passenger.list

i am added some words.

before:

```
deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger jammy main
```

after:

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger jammy main
```

just add **[arch=amd64]** and it works